# Matplotlib fig doesn't show updated data in plot despite data being retrievable using .get_data()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to display live data in my plots alongside a video and have that outputted via video to observe later. Was following this suggestion: [Combining cv2.imshow() with matplotlib plt.show() in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099734/combining-cv2-imshow-with-matplotlib-plt-show-in-real-time)

```
# I have redacted a fair bit of the code for other subplots 
# as I am just working on getting the one to display but if 
# you would like to see the rest let me know. Did this for simplicity.

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(9,16)
gs.update(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0.1, bottom=0.1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0:2,4:10])

speedArr = LapData["mSpeed"]*3.6 #Array of speed measured at time intervals
timeArr = LapData["mCurrentTime"] #Array of in-game lap time @ ^    ^

line1, = ax2.plot(timeArr, speedArr, "r")

print("Starting while loop to display video...")
x=0
telemetryLength = len(timeArr)
while cap.more():
    completionPerc = int(x/(vidLength/2)*len(timeArr))
    line1.set_data(np.array(timeArr[:completionPerc]),np.array(speedArr[:completionPerc]))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    print(line1.get_data())

    # convert canvas to image
    img = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
    img = img.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

    # img is rgb, convert to opencv's default bgr
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # display image with opencv or any operation you like
    cv2.imshow("plot",img)    # The img does not display updated graph
```

print(line1.get_data()) correctly outputs the x and y datasets every iteration as per below:

```
(array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64))
(array([ 0.5]), array([ 68.31216]))
(array([ 0.5]), array([ 68.31216]))
(array([ 0.5     ,  0.586975]), array([ 68.31216,  69.23736]))
(array([ 0.5     ,  0.586975]), array([ 68.31216,  69.23736]))
```

But the graph continues to not update???

Comment: I suppose you would want to update the axes limits after setting new data. `ax2.relim(); ax2.autoscale_view()`

Comment: Hmm I have seen that in a few sample codes. Debating if that was important as I had already set my x, y limits to the length of time. But perhaps I can just keep scaling the x to refresh the graph.