# How to draw a matplotlib plot on video with OpenCV

Tags: python, pandas, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV and a pandas dataframe to produce a video and draw data on the video frames from the dataframe. I can easily draw text data from the dataframe, but I am confused on how to draw a matplotlib on the video frame.

Inputs:
1 video
1 dataframe with data for each frame in the video as a row

Code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
numFrames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
dfi = df.iterrows()
assert len(dfi) == numFrames

def pipeline(frame):
    row = next(dfi[1])
    cv2.putText(frame, str(row.data), (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA, False)
    plot_to_add = plt.plot(row.time, row.data)
    ### how to do this
    cv2.draw(plot_to_add)

video = VideoFileClip(vid)
out_video = video.fl_image(pipeline)
out_video.write_videofile("vidout.mp4", temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

What I'm shooting for is something like this. Obviously not this fancy with all the color and effects, but a simple timeseries plot overlayed on the image.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099734/combining-cv2-imshow-with-matplotlib-plt-show-in-real-time/43101480#43101480) that extract pixel data from a plot to draw with `cv2.imshow`.

Comment: @QuangHoang This is helpful and the answer works, but I want to plot to be combined with the image, not two separate images.

Comment: that's a concept so you can extract plot data to a numpy array. Then you can use [`cv2.addweighted`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_image_arithmetics/py_image_arithmetics.html) to overlay your plot onto the frame with opencv.