# How to add matplotlib plot below and image in opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to add two plots to the bottom of an image. It should look like this:

`dog`

[image]

`plot` (both plots look very similar)

[image]

I want to combine these two images together, specifically attaching the plot to the bottom of the dog image. I want the result to look like:

[image]

This link was helpful in getting plots to the right image format, but I do not know how to attach them to the main image

[Combining cv2.imshow() with matplotlib plt.show() in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099734/combining-cv2-imshow-with-matplotlib-plt-show-in-real-time/43101480#43101480)

#### edit

High level pseudocode:

```
import cv2
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


vid = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
global data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

assert len(data) == cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAMES_COUNT()

def pipeline(frame):

    frame_index = next(dfi[0])
    current_plot1 = plt.plot(df.time[:frame_index], df.data1[:frame_index]
    current_plot2 = plt.plot(df.time[:frame_index], df.data2[:frame_index]
    
    # add plots to frame somehow here
    frame = frame+current_plot1+current_plot2
    return frame

# write video
dfi = df.iterrows()
video = VideoFileClip(vid)
out_video = video.fl_image(pipeline)
out_video.write_videofile("vidout.mp4", temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

Comment: Will the opencv image update or is it static? If it's static, and you can do a simple `imshow`, then you could arrange them like here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-gridspec-py

Comment: Ideally it can update. My overall goal is to make a video where the dog image is 1 of many frames and the plots get updated according to additional data for each frame.

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid, so you want to put in that window that `cv2.imshow` creates the two bottom graphs and update them dynamically? Or go from the captured images/frames from `cv2` into several frames in `matplotlib`, and in the end create a movie with pre-processed data?

Comment: No worries, I updated with some pseudocode to give a high level overview

Answer (score 0):

First use `plot1 = plt.figure()` similarly for `plot2 = plt.figure()` while initalizing the plots

then horizontally concat the plots

```
combined_plot=plt.hconcat([plot1,plot2])
```

then vertically concat these using

```
final_img=plt.vconcat([dog_img,combined_plot])

return final_img
```