# Python: how to get the intensity value of each pixel for a plot to use imshow() for plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a simple line plot to a 2D array of intensity so that it will be easy to update the image when new lines are added. I wonder how I can make the line plot into a 2D array that stores the intensity value of each pixel, then use imshow() for plotting?

e.g.:
The following code plots an image with two lines.

```
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
plt.plot(np.arange(5), [4,5,2,7,4], color="k", alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(np.arange(5), [4,6,2,8,4], color="k", alpha=0.3)
plt.axis('off')
fig.savefig("test.png", dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

[image]

What I want is to save the figure into a 2D array, instead of saving the figure as a png file. With the 2D array, I would be able to reproduce the image with plt.imshow() function.
The reason why I want to do it is to reduce the time when I make modifications on this image: when I need to remove a line or add a new line, I can simply do calculations with the 2D intensity array instead of keeping track of all the lines in the image.

Comment: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099734/combining-cv2-imshow-with-matplotlib-plt-show-in-real-time/43101480#43101480). Though there are better way to update the images with just add artist or something.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] that creates your plot, or something like it, and then show what you hope to obtain as a result so we can assist you properly. Thank you.

Comment: More explanations added. Thanks! @MarkSetchell

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks! I updated the question. Is this related to your original post?

Comment: You could save the plot to an *"in-memory"* (i.e. not on disk) PNG file and then load that from memory into an array.

Comment: @MarkSetchell But in that way I would only get the RGB values for each pixel, right? I want to have an array of intensity values so that I can easily add or remove lines to this picture. If I only have the RGB then I need to figure out a way to recalculate the RGB value for each pixel when new lines are added, which I think would be very difficult, right?

Comment: I don’t think I have understood your question. You say you want an array of intensity values which sounds exactly like a greyscale image to me which is easily derived from an RGB image. Maybe you can improve your question to show better what you want.